# Uploading large files with chunks using Javascript Dropbox API

Tags: javascript, upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

I was using this code to upload files to dropbox with Javascript (vuejs); however, I have not been able to get the files larger than 350 MB to load.  I have been trying to use chunks to load the file. The code doesn't error but I have been getting  a 400 error when the dropbox api returns the result:

Dropbox-sdk.min.js?0032:1 POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/append_v2 400 (Bad Request)

I am wondering if there was something wrong with the code or could there be something that needs to be changed in the dropbox settings? I have been using this code as a guide: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/javascript/upload/index.html#L2

```
       uploadToDropbox: function (path, file) {
            var dbx = this.dropbox()
            console.log("File upload .. " + path)
            console.log("File upload .. " + file)
            console.log(UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT)
            if (file.size < UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT) {
                this.dropbox().filesUpload({ path: path, contents: file })
                    //__PIPELINE\assets\test
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response)
                        //this.structure = response.result.entries;
                        console.log("This was successful")
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                        console.log("This is an error")
                    });
            }
            else {
                // File is bigger than 150 Mb - use filesUploadSession* API
                const maxBlob = 8 * 1000 * 1000; // 8Mb - Dropbox JavaScript API suggested max file / chunk size

                var workItems = [];

                var offset = 0;

                while (offset < file.size) {
                    var chunkSize = Math.min(maxBlob, file.size - offset);
                    workItems.push(file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize));
                    offset += chunkSize;
                }
                console.log ("Work Items : ")
                console.log (workItems)
                const task = workItems.reduce((acc, blob, idx, items) => {
                    if (idx == 0) {
                        // Starting multipart upload of file
                        console.log("idx is 0")
                        return acc.then(function () {
                            return dbx.filesUploadSessionStart({ close: false, contents: blob })
                                .then(response => response.session_id)
                        });
                    } else if (idx < items.length - 1) {
                        console.log("idx is less than items.length")
                        // Append part to the upload session
                        return acc.then(function (sessionId) {
                           
                            var cursor = { session_id: sessionId, offset: idx * maxBlob };
                            return dbx.filesUploadSessionAppendV2({ cursor: cursor, close: false, contents: blob }).then(() => sessionId);
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Last chunk of data, close session
                        console.log("finishing session")
                        return acc.then(function (sessionId) {
                            var cursor = { session_id: sessionId, offset: file.size - blob.size };
                            var commit = { path: '/' + file.name, mode: 'add', autorename: true, mute: false };
                            return dbx.filesUploadSessionFinish({ cursor: cursor, commit: commit, contents: blob });
                        });
                    }
                }, Promise.resolve());

                task.then(function (result) {
                    console.log(result)
                    //var results = document.getElementById('results');
                    //results.appendChild(document.createTextNode('File uploaded!'));
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
            }
        },
```

Comment: What's in the response body for that failing request? It should contain a more useful error message.

Comment: I didn't see much more in the failing request.  But I did figure out how to fix it. 
Someone else has the same issue.  It was a missing session id.  

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/351

This line should instead be:
.then(response => response.result.session_id)

Answer (score 0):

The session id was missing in the code.
The response object was updated in a new version of the sdk and the example code doesn't work anymore:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#4-updating-the-response-object

The fix is changing this line:

.then(response => response.result.session_id)

Here is a link to a thread on github with the same issue:
https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/351